# Independantly position div's within a parent div

Tags: html, css

I am trying to put 3 div children inside a parent div, where they have exact positions, and the children are not concerned about their siblings. I am trying to create a simple example, but all the child divs are relating to their siblings.

```css
.parent {
  position: relative;
  height: 224px;
  width: 224px;
  border: 32px solid lightgrey;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  height: 64px;
  width: 64px;
}

.child1 {
  top: 32px;
  left: 32px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

.child2 {
  top: 32px;
  left: 128px;
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

.child3 {
  width: 160px;
  top: 128px;
  left: 32px;
  background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child child1" />
  <div class="child child2" />
  <div class="child child3" />
</div>
```

Where I have tried looking:

- http://www.wickham43.net/divboxes.php
- [Position an HTML element relative to its container using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/104953/position-an-html-element-relative-to-its-container-using-css)
- [How to place div inside another div to absolute position?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15068624/how-to-place-div-inside-another-div-to-absolute-position)
- https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#comp-abspos

Comment: The problem is with your closing div, use `</div>` instead of `.../>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works when closing the `<div>` tag with `</div>` rather than using a single `<div />`.

This is because in HTML5, the slash at the end of non-void tags (like `div`) are [forbidden and ignored](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3558200/4472840). So your original code is interpreted as each child being nested inside the previous one; hence each one is relative to its prior "sibling" (actually, its parent).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rtuy7gva/1/)